# Computing a function and determining if continuous or not

Tags: calculus, self-learning

Let $f$ be given by:
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^2 & x \leq 2\\
2x &  2< x< 4\\
\sqrt{x} &x\geq 4
\end{cases}
$$

A: Compute $f(1)$, $f(2)$, $f(3)$, $f(4)$, and $f(5)$.

B: At what points if any is $f(x)$ discontinuous?

Im struggling with where to  calculate in the formula.

Thank You!

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than downvotes and votes to close if you edit the question to show us what you have tried and where you are stuck. Please use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: submitted edit using mathjax

Comment: make a sketch for the graph

Comment: @Lucky The edit was uncorrect, I've fixed it.

Comment: @garmichgang123 What values does $f(x)$ have at $ x=4 $ in your sketched graphs?

Comment: @garmishgang123 Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

As for when $f$ is discontinuous, you just need to check the points $2$ and $4$. Since $x^2$, $2x$, and $\sqrt{x}$ are all continuous, you have that $f$ is continuous on $(-\infty,2)\cup(2,4)\cup(4,\infty)$.

At $x=2$, you have
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 2^-}x^2=4$$
and 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 2^+}2x=4$$
Since these limits agree, $f$ is continuous at $x=2$. Now, at $x=4$, you have
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 4^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 4^-}2x=8$$
and 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 4^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 4^+}\sqrt{4}=2$$
Since this limits do NOT agree, $f$ is discontinuous at $x=4$.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the definition, for example

- $f(1) = 1^2=1$
- $f(2) = 2^2=4$
- $f(3) = 2\cdot 3=6$
- $f(4) = \sqrt 4=2$

Note also that

- $\lim_{x\to 4^-} f(x)\neq \lim_{x\to 4^+} f(x)$

Comment: why don't you take (3) to the 3rd power and (4) to the 4th and so on?

Comment: @garmischgang123 why (3) to the third power?

Comment: nvm I see what you did, f(5) is not possible correct?